# JavaScript library that will display variable size wedges on a Pie Chart

Tags: website-design, data-visualisation, javascript, chart-design

[image: Example pie chart with variable sized wedges]

I'm looking for a JavaScript library that will create pie charts with variable sized wedges like in the image. (It looks like a doughnut graph but the the image in the middle just has a white border around)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pie chart whose sectors extend variably from its center is generally called a polar area chart.

There are probably many more but I know [**chart.js**](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#polar-area-chart-introduction) can create these with no problem.

[image: Polar area chart]

- **http://www.chartjs.org**
- **https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js**